# "Trickiness" to calling Scala code from Java?

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

There is a Scala library (that only exists written in Scala) that I really want to use in my Java app. I am trying to evaluate whether I can do this or not without suffering any hidden gotchyas/caveats/pitfalls. So I went straight to the Scala FAQ, where [they answer this very question](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/266.html) (well, sort of):

> Accessing Java classes from Scala code is no problem at all. **Using a Scala class from Java can get tricky, in particular if your Scala class uses advanced features like generics, polymorphic methods, or abstract types.**

I then found several other sites (such as [this one](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~michelou/scala/using-scala-from-java.html)) that seem to indicate there is no problem in calling Scala from inside Java, as it is all compiled JVM bytecode.

So I have two very conflicting sources of information, and I'm stuck in the middle trying to determine what use cases make calling Scala from Java "*tricky*", and which use cases are straight forward. Any ideas?

Comment: Most of the issues that pop up during java / scala interaction are grouped around [scala-java-interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala-java-interop) tag which is worth looking at in your situation.

Comment: You could give the name of the Scala library you are trying to use, some users may have done the same and be able to provide some feedback.

Comment: Thanks @vptheron (+1) - sure, in this specific case it's the [Akka Quartz Scheduler](https://github.com/typesafehub/akka-quartz-scheduler) for any interested parties. However, I'm interested in a general rubric for making this determination for any future Scala libs I might also want to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the scala library you are calling uses "tricky" features, I suppose you could wrap it (in scala) in a manner such that the wrapper does not expose any of the "tricky" features to calling code.

Comment: Thanks @Arleigh (+1) - however I'm not following you... if some Scala method (let's call it `foo()`) does something that can't be called directly from Java, then if we wrap the `foo()` method in another Scala method, say, called `bar()`, then to the Java app what's the difference between calling `foo()` or calling `bar()`? They'll both execute the bytecode defined in `foo()`...

Comment: The "tricky" stuff you should worry about are with the methid api not it's implementation. If the method accept and return simple objects then it should work as is. If it use some special objects or use other advance scala stuff like implicits then you may as Arleigh suggest wrap it

Comment: There are method names which are legal in Scala, but illegal in Java, for example. Those methods cannot be called from Java, or more precisely you need to use their mangled name. Also, some simple Scala constructs may be compiled into very complex Java constructs. E.g. a trait will be compiled to a class with static methods, and when you mix a trait into a class, then the Scala compiler will inject forwarder methods into the class which forward any calls to the static methods. The Java compiler obviously doesn't know how to do this, so you cannot mix a trait into a Java class.