# Integrating both Java and Scala into one project

Tags: java, scala

I am very much familiar with Java and its Spring Framework.
So we are using spring boot project,where we have implemented various services using java, now we want to add few scala services(for spark implementation) in it.

So that I can easily handle requests from a controller (which is submitted by UI).

Can anyone suggest some different methods or best practices I can follow to build the project and create the service

It would be great help if you can explain with some examples or use cases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Trickiness" to calling Scala code from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895759/trickiness-to-calling-scala-code-from-java)

Comment: Need more details:
what kind of scala project / framework are you using?
Or do you need recommendations for one that is compatible with Spring?
Can you clarify if you want to use Spring and what you need from it?
In general using the dependency injection pattern of Spring can work but isn't idiomatic of scala.

Comment: no its not @jannis

Answer (score 1):

The method I use frequently to mix Java and Scala is Maven based.
Put Scala compiler plugin above Maven compiler plugin in your `pom.xml`:

```
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <!--<testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>-->
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <recompileMode>incremental</recompileMode>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <args>
                            <arg>-Ydelambdafy:method</arg>
                            <arg>-target:jvm-1.8</arg>
                            <arg>-deprecation</arg>
                            <arg>-feature</arg>
                            <arg>-unchecked</arg>
                            <arg>-language:implicitConversions</arg>
                            <arg>-language:postfixOps</arg>
                        </args>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <args>
                            <arg>-Ydelambdafy:method</arg>
                            <arg>-target:jvm-1.8</arg>
                            <arg>-deprecation</arg>
                            <arg>-feature</arg>
                            <arg>-unchecked</arg>
                            <arg>-language:implicitConversions</arg>
                            <arg>-language:postfixOps</arg>
                        </args>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerId>javac</compilerId>
                <debug>true</debug>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I created [a sample project at Github](https://github.com/YounesRahimi/maven-java-scala).